# Float Images when their is space available

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am making a site like Google Photos in that there is a Home page where I show all the photos uploaded by the user and it looks like this:-

[image]

The problem is when there is a big photo in a row (like the image in the middle of 1st row is big) because of that image the image in the next row has that **huge gap**. Is there any way it should automatically fill in the gaps if it's there! This is the code:-

(I am using Django to fetch the images from the server)

### HTML:-

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="upload" id="upload" style="display: none">
            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        {%for date, image_list in image_day reversed%}

        <div class="home">
            <h4 class="date">{{date}}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="image-gallery">
            <div class="row">
                {%for i in image_list reversed%}
                <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <img class="img1" id="img1" src="/media/{{i.image}}" style="width: 100%;"
                        onclick="popup('/media/{{i.image}}')">
                </div>
                {%endfor%}


            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

### CSS:-

```
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

        .home {
            font-family: 'Poppins';
            padding-top: 3%;
        }

        .img1 {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
            transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .image-gallery {
            padding-top: 1%;
        }

        .img1:hover {
            opacity: 0.9;
        }

        .upload {
            padding-top: 3%;
        }
    </style>
```

Please, Let me know if you want any more information!

Comment: You need to use CSS GRID and JavaScript to make it - https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Comment: The effect is called `masonry` and there are several questions about it. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra, I didn't know that! Thanks for referrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `column-count` for making a masonry gallery. Alternatively, you can use masonry scripts.

CSS Example:

```css
.gallery {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  
  <div class="gallery">
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the `column-width` property. One thing I consider worth noting is the order the images are placed: the columns ara filled one after another. So the first few images are all placed in the first row.

Comment: since it's a column, the order would be like 1, 4, 7 / 2, 5, 8 / 3, 6, 9. So if you need ordering like 1, 2, 3/ 4, 5, 6 (row-wise), I would suggest using a masonry plugin instead.